# How spy an autowired bean in Spring Tests

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

I have a simple logging handler beans configuration which I inject into an `IntegrationFlow`

```
@Configuration
class LogHandlerConfiguration {

    private LoggingHandler handler;

    @Bean
    public MessageHandler kafkaSuccessHandler() {
        return getLogger(LoggingHandler.Level.INFO);
    }

    @Bean(name="kafkaFailureHandler")
    public MessageHandler kafkaFailureHandler() {
        return getLogger(LoggingHandler.Level.ERROR);
    }

    private LoggingHandler getLogger(LoggingHandler.Level level) {
        handler = new LoggingHandler(level);
        handler.setShouldLogFullMessage(Boolean.TRUE);
        return handler;
    }
}
```

the integration flow to test

```
@Bean
IntegrationFlow kafkaFailureFlow(ExecutorChannel kafkaErrorChannel, MessageHandler kafkaFailureHandler) {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(kafkaErrorChannel)
            .transform("payload.failedMessage")
            .handle(kafkaFailureHandler)
            .get();
}
```

Here's my test

```
@SpyBean
MessageHandler kafkaFailureHandler;

@BeforeEach
public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(KafkaPublishFailureTest.class);
}

@Test
void testFailedKafkaPublish() {

    //Dummy message
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("key", "value");
    // Publish Message
    Message<Map<String, String>> message = MessageBuilder.withPayload(map)
            .setHeader("X-UPSTREAM-TYPE", "alm")
            .setHeader("X-UPSTREAM-INSTANCE", "jira")
            .setHeader("X-MESSAGE-KEY", "key-1")
            .build();

    kafkaGateway.publish(message);
    // Failure handler called
    Mockito.verify(kafkaFailureHandler, Mockito.timeout(0).atLeastOnce()).handleMessage(
            ArgumentMatchers.any(Message.class));
}
```

We've created a generic Kafka Producer, Consumer configuration to which downsteam apps can attach failure and success handler best suited to their needs. I'm not able to verify the the `LoggingHandler` in this case is called atleast once.

The `failureHandler` gets executed under an `ExecturoeChannel` backed by `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`

```
@Bean
ExecutorChannel kafkaErrorChannel(Executor threadPoolExecutor) {
    return MessageChannels.executor("kafkaErrorChannel", threadPoolExecutor).get();
}
```

failures are handled via retry advice

```
@Bean
RequestHandlerRetryAdvice retryAdvice(ExecutorChannel kafkaErrorChannel) {
    RequestHandlerRetryAdvice retryAdvice = new RequestHandlerRetryAdvice();
    retryAdvice.setRecoveryCallback(new ErrorMessageSendingRecoverer(kafkaErrorChannel));
    return retryAdvice;
}
```

I get this error when I run the test

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No bean found for definition [SpyDefinition@44dfdd58 name = '', typeToSpy = org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandler, reset = AFTER]
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:97) ~[spring-core-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoPostProcessor.inject(MockitoPostProcessor.java:351) ~[spring-boot-test-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
```

Comment: Can you share, please, a simple project to let us to play and reproduce?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anadimisra/a305280a5507af15e2809e6b17f5ea9d, here's all the classes in my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, was hung up over **Why not** `@SpyBean`? There were two problems

1. both success and failure handlers were MessageHandlers confusing `@SpyBean`
2. The Kafka producer waiting time was too high, i.e. 1000ms

Here's what Finally worked, using a named bean

```
@Bean("kafkaFailureHandler")
public MessageHandler kafkaFailureHandler() {
    LoggingHandler handler = new LoggingHandler(LoggingHandler.Level.INFO);
    handler.setShouldLogFullMessage(Boolean.TRUE);
    return handler;
}
```

and then in tests reducing the max block too

```
@DirtiesContext
@SpringBootTest(classes = {KafkaHandlerConfiguration.class, SwiftalkKafkaGateway.class})
@SpringIntegrationTest(noAutoStartup = {"kafkaFailureFlow"})
@TestPropertySource(properties = {
        "spring.main.banner-mode=off",
        "logging.level.root=INFO",
        "logging.level.org.springframework=INFO",
        "logging.level.org.springframework.integration=DEBUG",
        "spring.kafka.producer.properties.max.block.ms=50",
        "spring.kafka.producer.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9999",
        "spring.kafka.producer.key-serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer",
        "spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer",
})
public class KafkaPublishFailureTest {

    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(KafkaPublishFailureTest.class);

    @Autowired
    SwiftalkKafkaGateway kafkaGateway;

    @SpyBean(name = "kafkaFailureHandler")
    MessageHandler kafkaFailureHandler;

    @Test
    @SuppressWarnings("all")
    void testFailedKafkaPublish() throws InterruptedException {

        //Dummy message
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("key", "value");
        // Publish Message
        Message<Map<String, String>> message = MessageBuilder.withPayload(map)
                .setHeader("X-UPSTREAM-TYPE", "alm")
                .setHeader("X-UPSTREAM-INSTANCE", "jira")
                .setHeader("X-MESSAGE-KEY", "key-1")
                .build();

        kafkaGateway.publish(message);
        verify(this.kafkaFailureHandler, timeout(500)).handleMessage(any(Message.class));
    }

}
```

notice the `spring.kafka.producer.properties.max.block.ms=50` and `verify(this.kafkaFailureHandler, timeout(500)).handleMessage(any(Message.class));`

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I've tried and ti works:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Demo1Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Demo1Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    ExecutorChannel kafkaErrorChannel(TaskExecutor taskExecutor) {
        return new ExecutorChannel(taskExecutor);
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageHandler kafkaFailureHandler() {
        LoggingHandler handler = new LoggingHandler(LoggingHandler.Level.ERROR);
        handler.setShouldLogFullMessage(Boolean.TRUE);
        return handler;
    }

    @Bean
    IntegrationFlow kafkaFailureFlow(ExecutorChannel kafkaErrorChannel, MessageHandler kafkaFailureHandler) {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(kafkaErrorChannel)
                .transform("payload.failedMessage")
                .handle(kafkaFailureHandler)
                .get();
    }

}
```

---

```
@SpringBootTest
class Demo1ApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    ExecutorChannel kafkaErrorChannel;

    @SpyBean
    MessageHandler kafkaFailureHandler;

    @Test
    void testSpyBean() throws InterruptedException {
        MessagingException payload = new MessageHandlingException(new GenericMessage<>("test"));
        this.kafkaErrorChannel.send(new ErrorMessage(payload));
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        Mockito.verify(this.kafkaFailureHandler).handleMessage(ArgumentMatchers.any(Message.class));
    }

}
```

Perhaps your problem that you don't include `LogHandlerConfiguration` into your `@SpringBootTest` configuration. That's why I asked a simple project to play with.
Your code with all those properties are too custom to just copy/paste into my environment...

Also pay attention to that `Thread.sleep(1000);`. Since your `kafkaErrorChannel` is an `ExecutorChannel`, the message consumption happens on a different thread leaving your main testing thread and leading to a failure because of race condition. It is hard to guess the proper timing, so better to stub a mock method to fulfill some thread barrier like `new CountDownLatch(1)` and wait for it in the test.

Out of subject you can also investigate Spring Integration Testing Framework: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/testing.html#test-context

Comment: I was using `timeout` method in `Mockito` to no avail; I’ll try stubbing the latch.

Comment: Did you solve an original issue with `No bean found for definition`?

Comment: Nah, I tried on `MockIntegrationContext` and `ChannelInterceptor` too but there too it was failing given my wait logic wasn’t effective.

Comment: Is that channel really has to be an `ExecutorChannel`? Although I think this is already not relevant to the original question. What else on the matter I can help you with?

Comment: Well this code goes into a hub that handles all pub/sub to/from Kafka, wouldn’t using an `ExecutorChannel` improve the the throughput?

Comment: I would say `QueueChannel` is better then, since you don't care when an error is going to be handled. However according your current code, it looks like you just log that error. Therefore a `DirectChannel` should be enough: it is some milliseconds slower for one caller, but you win with multi of them since you won't spawn extra threads for just error logging. Anyway some better race condition handling in your test logic is the way to go for the current state of code.

Comment: Using log handler only for purpose of tests, at runtime there would be a handler that saves it to Mongo or RDBMS after successful publish to Kafka and that’s decided by the environment in which it’s running, my intention is not spend waiting time on those  IO operations by moving them to background job of sorts. Is this the right approach?

Comment: Ah sorry I should have put a separate thread to it. I've settled with to using a Channel Interceptor to inspect message and `Awatility` to wait on the queue; that helped and that's because `SpyBean` just didn't go beyond throwing the same error.

Comment: Good. Probably better to accept the answer to let other people know that there is a solution in this thread?